# Drawing on canvas, offset is 100px off

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, canvas

I know it´s not well seen, that you post a link to a code, but I followed this tutorial of making a html drawing canvas app and implemented the source to my wordpress site and everything works fine, except, that all the mouse-click-events seems offset to the left by `100px`.

If I open the example html, everything works fine, so I think it has something to do with the parent container css´s or something.

Since I am not very well in js, I thought maybe you can help me figure it out, since I try since a few days now.

[This](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app/) is the tutorial and source code and this is the code of the js file

```
var drawingApp = (function () {

    "use strict";

    var canvas,
        context,
        canvasWidth = 490,
        canvasHeight = 220,
        colorPurple = "#cb3594",
        colorGreen = "#659b41",
        colorYellow = "#ffcf33",
        colorBrown = "#986928",
        outlineImage = new Image(),
        crayonImage = new Image(),
        markerImage = new Image(),
        eraserImage = new Image(),
        crayonBackgroundImage = new Image(),
        markerBackgroundImage = new Image(),
        eraserBackgroundImage = new Image(),
        crayonTextureImage = new Image(),
        clickX = [],
        clickY = [],
        clickColor = [],
        clickTool = [],
        clickSize = [],
        clickDrag = [],
        paint = false,
        curColor = colorPurple,
        curTool = "crayon",
        curSize = "normal",
        mediumStartX = 18,
        mediumStartY = 19,
        mediumImageWidth = 93,
        mediumImageHeight = 46,
        drawingAreaX = 111,
        drawingAreaY = 11,
        drawingAreaWidth = 267,
        drawingAreaHeight = 200,
        toolHotspotStartY = 23,
        toolHotspotHeight = 38,
        sizeHotspotStartY = 157,
        sizeHotspotHeight = 36,
        totalLoadResources = 8,
        curLoadResNum = 0,
        sizeHotspotWidthObject = {
            huge: 39,
            large: 25,
            normal: 18,
            small: 16
        },

        // Clears the canvas.
        clearCanvas = function () {

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        },

        // Redraws the canvas.
        redraw = function () {

            var locX,
                locY,
                radius,
                i,
                selected,

                drawCrayon = function (x, y, color, selected) {

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(x + 41, y + 11);
                    context.lineTo(x + 41, y + 35);
                    context.lineTo(x + 29, y + 35);
                    context.lineTo(x + 29, y + 33);
                    context.lineTo(x + 11, y + 27);
                    context.lineTo(x + 11, y + 19);
                    context.lineTo(x + 29, y + 13);
                    context.lineTo(x + 29, y + 11);
                    context.lineTo(x + 41, y + 11);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fillStyle = color;
                    context.fill();

                    if (selected) {
                        context.drawImage(crayonImage, x, y, mediumImageWidth, mediumImageHeight);
                    } else {
                        context.drawImage(crayonImage, 0, 0, 59, mediumImageHeight, x, y, 59, mediumImageHeight);
                    }
                },

                drawMarker = function (x, y, color, selected) {

                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(x + 10, y + 24);
                    context.lineTo(x + 10, y + 24);
                    context.lineTo(x + 22, y + 16);
                    context.lineTo(x + 22, y + 31);
                    context.closePath();
                    context.fillStyle = color;
                    context.fill();

                    if (selected) {
                        context.drawImage(markerImage, x, y, mediumImageWidth, mediumImageHeight);
                    } else {
                        context.drawImage(markerImage, 0, 0, 59, mediumImageHeight, x, y, 59, mediumImageHeight);
                    }
                };

            // Make sure required resources are loaded before redrawing
            if (curLoadResNum < totalLoadResources) {
                return;
            }

            clearCanvas();

            if (curTool === "crayon") {

                // Draw the crayon tool background
                context.drawImage(crayonBackgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                // Draw purple crayon
                selected = (curColor === colorPurple);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY = 19;
                drawCrayon(locX, locY, colorPurple, selected);

                // Draw green crayon
                selected = (curColor === colorGreen);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY += 46;
                drawCrayon(locX, locY, colorGreen, selected);

                // Draw yellow crayon
                selected = (curColor === colorYellow);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY += 46;
                drawCrayon(locX, locY, colorYellow, selected);

                // Draw brown crayon
                selected = (curColor === colorBrown);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY += 46;
                drawCrayon(locX, locY, colorBrown, selected);

            } else if (curTool === "marker") {

                // Draw the marker tool background
                context.drawImage(markerBackgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

                // Draw purple marker
                selected = (curColor === colorPurple);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY = 19;
                drawMarker(locX, locY, colorPurple, selected);

                // Draw green marker
                selected = (curColor === colorGreen);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY += 46;
                drawMarker(locX, locY, colorGreen, selected);

                // Draw yellow marker
                selected = (curColor === colorYellow);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY += 46;
                drawMarker(locX, locY, colorYellow, selected);

                // Draw brown marker
                selected = (curColor === colorBrown);
                locX = selected ? 18 : 52;
                locY += 46;
                drawMarker(locX, locY, colorBrown, selected);

            } else if (curTool === "eraser") {

                context.drawImage(eraserBackgroundImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
                context.drawImage(eraserImage, 18, 19, mediumImageWidth, mediumImageHeight);
            }

            // Draw line on ruler to indicate size
            switch (curSize) {
            case "small":
                locX = 467;
                break;
            case "normal":
                locX = 450;
                break;
            case "large":
                locX = 428;
                break;
            case "huge":
                locX = 399;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            locY = 189;
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(locX, locY, 2, 12);
            context.closePath();
            context.fillStyle = '#333333';
            context.fill();

            // Keep the drawing in the drawing area
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(drawingAreaX, drawingAreaY, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);
            context.clip();

            // For each point drawn
            for (i = 0; i < clickX.length; i += 1) {

                // Set the drawing radius
                switch (clickSize[i]) {
                case "small":
                    radius = 2;
                    break;
                case "normal":
                    radius = 5;
                    break;
                case "large":
                    radius = 10;
                    break;
                case "huge":
                    radius = 20;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                // Set the drawing path
                context.beginPath();
                // If dragging then draw a line between the two points
                if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
                } else {
                    // The x position is moved over one pixel so a circle even if not dragging
                    context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
                }
                context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);

                // Set the drawing color
                if (clickTool[i] === "eraser") {
                    //context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; // To erase instead of draw over with white
                    context.strokeStyle = 'white';
                } else {
                    //context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; // To erase instead of draw over with white
                    context.strokeStyle = clickColor[i];
                }
                context.lineCap = "round";
                context.lineJoin = "round";
                context.lineWidth = radius;
                context.stroke();
            }
            context.closePath();
            //context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";// To erase instead of draw over with white
            context.restore();

            // Overlay a crayon texture (if the current tool is crayon)
            if (curTool === "crayon") {
                context.globalAlpha = 0.4; // No IE support
                context.drawImage(crayonTextureImage, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            }
            context.globalAlpha = 1; // No IE support

            // Draw the outline image
            context.drawImage(outlineImage, drawingAreaX, drawingAreaY, drawingAreaWidth, drawingAreaHeight);
        },

        // Adds a point to the drawing array.
        // @param x
        // @param y
        // @param dragging
        addClick = function (x, y, dragging) {

            clickX.push(x);
            clickY.push(y);
            clickTool.push(curTool);
            clickColor.push(curColor);
            clickSize.push(curSize);
            clickDrag.push(dragging);
        },

        // Add mouse and touch event listeners to the canvas
        createUserEvents = function () {

            var press = function (e) {
                // Mouse down location
                var sizeHotspotStartX,
                    mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
                    mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

                if (mouseX < drawingAreaX) { // Left of the drawing area
                    if (mouseX > mediumStartX) {
                        if (mouseY > mediumStartY && mouseY < mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight) {
                            curColor = colorPurple;
                        } else if (mouseY > mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight && mouseY < mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight * 2) {
                            curColor = colorGreen;
                        } else if (mouseY > mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight * 2 && mouseY < mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight * 3) {
                            curColor = colorYellow;
                        } else if (mouseY > mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight * 3 && mouseY < mediumStartY + mediumImageHeight * 4) {
                            curColor = colorBrown;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (mouseX > drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth) { // Right of the drawing area

                    if (mouseY > toolHotspotStartY) {
                        if (mouseY > sizeHotspotStartY) {
                            sizeHotspotStartX = drawingAreaX + drawingAreaWidth;
                            if (mouseY < sizeHotspotStartY + sizeHotspotHeight && mouseX > sizeHotspotStartX) {
                                if (mouseX < sizeHotspotStartX + sizeHotspotWidthObject.huge) {
                                    curSize = "huge";
                                } else if (mouseX < sizeHotspotStartX + sizeHotspotWidthObject.large + sizeHotspotWidthObject.huge) {
                                    curSize = "large";
                                } else if (mouseX < sizeHotspotStartX + sizeHotspotWidthObject.normal + sizeHotspotWidthObject.large + sizeHotspotWidthObject.huge) {
                                    curSize = "normal";
                                } else if (mouseX < sizeHotspotStartX + sizeHotspotWidthObject.small + sizeHotspotWidthObject.normal + sizeHotspotWidthObject.large + sizeHotspotWidthObject.huge) {
                                    curSize = "small";
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (mouseY < toolHotspotStartY + toolHotspotHeight) {
                                curTool = "crayon";
                            } else if (mouseY < toolHotspotStartY + toolHotspotHeight * 2) {
                                curTool = "marker";
                            } else if (mouseY < toolHotspotStartY + toolHotspotHeight * 3) {
                                curTool = "eraser";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                paint = true;
                addClick(mouseX, mouseY, false);
                redraw();
            },

                drag = function (e) {
                    if (paint) {
                        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
                        redraw();
                    }
                    // Prevent the whole page from dragging if on mobile
                    e.preventDefault();
                },

                release = function () {
                    paint = false;
                    redraw();
                },

                cancel = function () {
                    paint = false;
                };

            // Add mouse event listeners to canvas element
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", press, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", release);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", cancel, false);

            // Add touch event listeners to canvas element
            canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", press, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchend", release, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", cancel, false);
        },

        // Calls the redraw function after all neccessary resources are loaded.
        resourceLoaded = function () {

            curLoadResNum += 1;
            if (curLoadResNum === totalLoadResources) {
                redraw();
                createUserEvents();
            }
        },

        // Creates a canvas element, loads images, adds events, and draws the canvas for the first time.
        init = function () {

            // Create the canvas (Neccessary for IE because it doesn't know what a canvas element is)
            canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
            canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
            canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
            document.getElementById('canvasDiv').appendChild(canvas);
            if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== "undefined") {
                canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
            }
            context = canvas.getContext("2d"); // Grab the 2d canvas context
            // Note: The above code is a workaround for IE 8 and lower. Otherwise we could have used:
            //     context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

            // Load images
            crayonImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            crayonImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/crayon-outline.png";

            markerImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            markerImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/marker-outline.png";

            eraserImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            eraserImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/eraser-outline.png";

            crayonBackgroundImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            crayonBackgroundImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/crayon-background.png";

            markerBackgroundImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            markerBackgroundImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/marker-background.png";

            eraserBackgroundImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            eraserBackgroundImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/eraser-background.png";

            crayonTextureImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            crayonTextureImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/crayon-texture.png";

            outlineImage.onload = resourceLoaded;
            outlineImage.src = cvtemplateDir+ "/images/watermelon-duck-outline.png";
        };

    return {
        init: init
    };
}());
```

It´s being implemented on my website [here](http://web318.login-11.hoststar.at/uni/kleinraum/mitarchpoint/?archpoint=entwurfsaspekte-der-gebaeudelehre)

This is the code to initialize it, which is being called on the hook:

```
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'canvas_comments');

function canvas_comments() {
?>  

 <div id="canvasDiv" style="width:490px;height:220px;"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
         drawingApp.init();
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just realized in Firefox it´s offsetting even more, I used chrome

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to get offsetTop and offsetLeft explicitly from the canvas?

You are now accessing offsetTop by *this* in a listener-function. Are you sure that *this* points to your canvas and not to something else?

Comment: just tried replacing all to canvas.offsetLeft and canvas.offsetTop, but doesnt change much. altough when i play around with the demo i recognized, that it starts to have the same behaviour, when i set the canvasdiv-position to absolute and margin-left:200px;. i created a, voila, non-working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33ba5wsx/3/

Comment: Mmmh that is strange... you could try canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), maybe this will have a different behavior. Otherwise I would suggest, that you create a jsfiddle, so that people here can test your code in an better way

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. Chrome complains about cvtemplateDir. its not defined ;-)

Comment: yes, it´s defined in my header to get the template-directory into the js file. This part works fine (It´s for the background-images) I now deleted them from the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/33ba5wsx/4/

Comment: i´m not sure how to use canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), instead of offset? how would i apply it? thx in advance

Comment: see http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/ for an example how to use getBoundingBoxRect()

Comment: Mr, you saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed with treeno´s suggestion to use canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

I inserted it at the end of the createUserEvents-function like this:

```
                cancel = function () {
    ......

var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            // Add mouse event listeners to canvas element
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", press, false);
            .....
        },
```

And finally i replaced every this.OffsetLeft and this.OffsetTop with rect.left and rect.top

Works like a charm!